# Cannot send table format to gmail using PHPmailer.

Tags: php, phpmailer

I used MsgHTML() function to send this mail body. 
isHTML is enabled in mailer script.
The HTML tags like 
 are rendered in mail, Inline style also worked.
But the table was not rendered in gmail. Inbox showing the plain text. Images are displayed clearly.

**PHP CODE**

```
$pd_details.='  
<table > 
  <th>Prod no  |</th>  <th>Prod name   |</th> <th>Prod price   |</th> <th>Prod quantity   |</th> <th>Prod image   |</th>
      <tr><td>'.$c.'</td><td>'.$pname.'</td><td>'.$total.'</td><td>'.$quant.'</td<td>'.$pdimg.'</td></tr>
</table>

Total Price is : '.$sum.' ';
```

Comment: make sure he whole message body is valid html

Comment: @Dagon What That means ?? Cannot understand.

Comment: yes, maybe you have some html error so gmail cannot render it.

Comment: @Dagon I don't think so dude. Because other HTML heading takes line break tags are working fine.

Comment: Just [validate your HTML](http://validator.w3.org) like he said! For a start you're missing a `tr` around your `th`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try this...  

                $from='sender details';  
                $to='receiver email address';  
                $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";  
                $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";  
                $headers .= 'From:'.$from. "\r\n";  

                $body='<table > 
      <th>Prod no  |</th>  <th>Prod name   |</th> <th>Prod price   |</th> <th>Prod quantity   |</th> <th>Prod image   |</th>
          <tr><td>'.$c.'</td><td>'.$pname.'</td><td>'.$total.'</td><td>'.$quant.'</td<td>'.$pdimg.'</td></tr>
    </table>';  

                $subject="subject";  
                ini_set("sendmail_from",$from);  
                @mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);
```